# Angular 6 [ngClass] not working with boolean in component.js

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

What I'm trying to do is hide text when ngState is true. When a certain element is clicked, that state is set to true. The [ngClass] should then add the hide class and hide the text. This first snippet is from the component.ts which outlines the boolean variable and the function which sets it to true.

```
export class MainMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  ngState = false;
    constructor() {

  }
  newGame(){
    this.ngState = this.ngState === true ? false : true;
    console.log(this.ngState);
  }
}
```

This next snippet is the component html

```
<canvas id='sparkCanvas'></canvas>
<div class="menuBox">
    <div class="title" [ngClass]="{'hide': ngState}">Dark Shards</div>
    <div class="optContainer">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let opt of opts" class="{{opt.class}}" [ngClass]="{'hide': ngState}"  (click)="opt.f()">{{opt.n}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the hide class below

```
.hide{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

When I replace [ngClass]="{'hide': ngState}" with [ngClass]="{'hide': ***true***}"

It will then work as intended. What am I not understanding here?

Here is a link to my code with a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fg48ro?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: everything seems fine. Did the `newGame` func get called to change the flag to true? can you provide code snippet with plunker or something?

Comment: I can definitely try, but on plunker it looks like it only supports older versions of angular. I created my project using 'ng new my-app' in the command console, so I'm not sure how I can recreate that within plunker or code pen. It may take me some time to figure that out since it doesn't seem to support it up front from what I am reading

Comment: You can try with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Yup. Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdh8eh

Comment: Did you save your stackblitz?

Comment: ah I don't think it's saving. I need to create an account or something

Comment: client-9e9ec2eb7262cea9047aa.js:1 PATCH https://stackblitz.com/api/projects/angular-fg48ro 500 ()

stackblitz is failing to save. that's the error message I get when I hit the save button

Comment: You could create a new stackblitz project in another tab or window, and try saving it. If it works, you could then transfer the code to that project.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fg48ro?file=src%2Findex.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without **`Quote`**

```
  <li *ngFor="let opt of opts" class="{{opt.class}}" [ngClass]="{hide: ngState}"  (click)="opt.f()">{{opt.n}}</li>
```

**EDIT**

When i see your code, the issue is not related to angular, but with javascript context, you need to specifiy the context of this like

**`' f: this.newGame.bind(this),'`**

[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssk2r8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain-menu%2Fmain-menu.component.ts)

Comment: I tried without a quote on hide before posting my question

Comment: so why do you downvote which is not mentioned in the quesiton! can you provide a stackblitz

Comment: I didn't down vote, I think someone else did. I'm sorry.

Comment: did you produce in stackblitz

Comment: what should happen?

Comment: for now I'm just trying to get the title to become hidden with the hide class

Comment: when I try that with angular it gives template parse error if there are multiple classes